# DOM parsing error in RSS FEED

Tags: parsing, dom

I need to parse the this xml file and need to display in the list view but I got the problem while running this code. 
    Any one please help me over come this problem
    Thank you in advance

This is XML file from the source http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0"

```
<rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>MobileNations</title>
    <description>
      Mobile Nations brings to you the very best of Android Central, CrackBerry.com, PreCentral.net, TiPb.com, and WPCentral
    </description>
    <link>http://www.mobilenations.com/</link>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 07 Aug 2013 06:15:01 -0400</lastBuildDate>
    <pubDate>Wed, 07 Aug 2013 06:15:01 -0400</pubDate>
    <item>
      <title>
        AT&T activates new 4G LTE markets, expands coverage in others
      </title>
      <description>
        <p class="rtecenter"><img alt="AT&amp;T" class="lightbox2 imagecache-w680h550 aligncenter" src="http://cdn.androidcentral.com/sites/androidcentral.com/files/imagecache/w680h550/postimages/108579/att-store-2.jpg" /></p> <h3> Six new markets, expanded coverage in Washington, D.C. and San Francisco areas</h3> <p><a href="http://www.androidcentral.com/tags/att" title="AT&amp;T">AT&amp;T</a> sends word that it&#39;s switched on 4G LTE service in six new markets, while expanding coverage in two major cities.</p> <p>From today, AT&amp;T LTE&nbsp;should be available in&nbsp;&mdash;</p> <p><a href="http://www.androidcentral.com/att-activates-new-4g-lte-markets-expands-coverage-others" target="_blank">read more</a></p>
      </description>
      <link>
        http://www.androidcentral.com/att-activates-new-4g-lte-markets-expands-coverage-others
      </link>
      <pubDate>Wed, 07 Aug 2013 09:48:24 +0000</pubDate>
      <category domain="http://www.androidcentral.com/articles/news">News</category>
      <category domain="http://www.androidcentral.com/tags/4g">4g</category>
      <category domain="http://www.androidcentral.com/tags/att-0">at&t</category>
      <category domain="http://www.androidcentral.com/tags/lte">lte</category>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">32622 at http://www.androidcentral.com</guid>
      <comments>
        http://www.androidcentral.com/att-activates-new-4g-lte-markets-expands-coverage-others#comments
      </comments>
      <dc:creator>Alex Dobie</dc:creator>
    </item>
```

My DOM parser code is

```
package com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.parser;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.util.Log;

public class DOMParser {

    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(xml);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            // Get all <item> tags.
            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            Log.i("this is the test message"+length, xml);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Node currentNode = nl.item(i);
                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                NodeList nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                int clength = nchild.getLength();

                Log.i("this is the test message total child nodes"+clength, xml);
                // Get the required elements from each Item
                // Ishwor changed the code j=0 and j= j+1
                for (int j = 0; j < clength; j = j + 1) {
                    Log.i("first child node name is"+nchild.item(j).getNodeName(), xml);

                    Node thisNode = nchild.item(j);
                    String theString = null;


                    //ishwor changed as
                    if (thisNode != null && thisNode.getFirstChild() != null) {
                        theString = thisNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    }
                    if (theString != null) {

                        String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();



                        /*


                    String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();

                    //theString = nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                    if(nchild.item(j).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()!=null){
                    //if (theString != null) {
                        //String nodeName = thisNode.getNodeName();


                         */
                        if ("title".equals(nodeName)) {
                            // Node name is equals to 'title' so set the Node
                            // value to the Title in the RSSItem.
                            _item.setTitle(theString);

                            Log.i("this is the test message"+theString, xml);

                        }

                        else if ("description".equals(nodeName)) {
                            _item.setDescription(theString);

                            Log.i("this is the test message"+theString, xml);

                            // Parse the html description to get the image url
                            String html = theString;
                            org.jsoup.nodes.Document docHtml = Jsoup.parse(html);
                            Elements imgEle = docHtml.select("img");
                            _item.setImage(imgEle.attr("src"));
                        }

                        else if ("pubDate".equals(nodeName)) {

                            // We replace the plus and zero's in the date with
                            // empty string
                            String formatedDate = theString.replace(" +0000",
                                    "");
                            _item.setDate(formatedDate);
                        }

                    }
                }

                // add item to the list
                _feed.addItem(_item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;
    }

}
```

MY log cat Error is

```
08-08 12:52:55.059: W/dalvikvm(3484): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a692a0)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.parser.DOMParser.parseXml(DOMParser.java:102)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.Splash$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(Splash.java:131)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at com.wfwf.everestnewsapp.Splash$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(Splash.java:1)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

08-08 12:52:55.064: E/AndroidRuntime(3484):     ... 5 more
```

Comment: There's a lot of important information missing here. What error are you getting? What language are you using the parse the XML? Show us the errors and the code that's generating them.

Comment: This line seems important: "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup"

Answer (score 0):

Try This Example...

```
    import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingDOMExample extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> description;
    ArrayList<String> pubDate;

    ItemAdapter adapter1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        description = new ArrayList<String>();  
        pubDate = new ArrayList<String>();  

        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "Your URL");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("title");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                Log.v("title--", ""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
                title.add(""+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("description");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
                Log.v("description--", ""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());            
                description.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());   

                NodeList websiteList1 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("pubDate");
                Element websiteElement1 = (Element) websiteList1.item(0);
                websiteList1 = websiteElement1.getChildNodes();

                pubDate.add(""+ ((Node) websiteList1.item(0)).getNodeValue());  

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

        adapter1 = new ItemAdapter(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }


    class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        final LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private class ViewHolder {
            public TextView title_text;
            public TextView des_text;
            public TextView date_text;
        }

        public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
        }

        //@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return title.size();
        }

        //@Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mainpage_listitem_activity, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.title_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
                holder.des_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.des_text);
                holder.date_text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_text);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.title_text.setText(""+title.get(position));

            holder.des_text.setText(""+Html.fromHtml(description.get(position)));
            holder.date_text.setText(""+pubDate.get(position));         

        return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I found the solution .. :) @hariharan